# Selenium Test Case Optimisation Advice

Tags: javascript, testing, ide, selenium, automated-tests

I have written a test case that compares two arrays, removing elements that match and throwing an execption for element that don't match.

It works, however the test is large and messy. Can anyone identify areas that could be improved upon .i.e optimized?

```
System.out.println(globalArray);
String[] array = selenium.getAllFields();
System.out.println(array);
String length = selenium.getEval("storedVars.array.length");
System.out.println(length);
String  = selenium.getEval("storedVars.length--");
System.out.println(length);
String index1 = "-1";
// ////////
// selenium.label("loop1");
System.out.println(selenium.getEval("storedVars.index1<storedVars.array.length"));
// selenium.while("storedVars.index1<${length}");
String  = selenium.getEval("storedVars.index1++");
System.out.println("FORM ARRAY INDEX: " + index1);
String id = selenium.getEval("storedVars.array[storedVars.index1]");
System.out.println("MATCH: " + id);
// ////////
// selenium.label("loop2");
String index2 = "-1";
// selenium.while("storedVars.index2<storedVars.globalArray.length");
String  = selenium.getEval("storedVars.index2++");
System.out.println("GLOBAL ARRAY INDEX: " + index2);
String size = selenium.getEval("storedVars.globalArray.length");
String  = selenium.getEval("if (storedVars.id == storedVars.globalArray[storedVars.index2]){storedVars.globalArray.splice (storedVars.index2,1); }");
System.out.println("SIZE: " + globalArray);
// selenium.endWhile();
// ////////
// selenium.goto("loop1");
// selenium.endWhile();
// ////////
String length = selenium.getEval("storedVars.globalArray.length");
String  = selenium.getEval("storedVars.length--");
System.out.println(length);
String index3 = "-1";
// selenium.while("storedVars.index3<${length}");
String  = selenium.getEval("storedVars.index3++");
System.out.println(index3);
verifyEquals("All Fields Present", selenium.getExpression(selenium.getEval("if(storedVars.length == 0){storedVars.outcome='All Fields Present';} else {storedVars.outcome='Missing Field: ' + storedVars.globalArray[storedVars.index3];}")));
// selenium.endWhile();
```

If the code is too hard to follow please say and i'll add better comments

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming at this from a java perspective, but in my opinion, Selenium is better suited for automating browser and end-user-regression-type testing. It looks like you're trying to use it as a unit test framework. Perhaps a unit test framework would be a better choice?

From this question, it looks like qunit is a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692873/javascript-unit-testing-frameworks

- Dave

Comment: I not really using it for unit testing you see, the AUT have a large number of different configuartions. A typical problem when regression testing is that fields often get turned off breaking the tests.

Comment: I'm not really using it for unit testing you see. The AUT has a large number of different configuartions. A typical problem when regression testing is that fields often get turned off breaking the tests preventing execution of the test suite. QA is often told by DEV "its turned off, just work around it,its not suposed to be on for this customer or we will switch on later"

Comment: Sorry I didn't realease the code clause had converted it into Selenium RC code.The test case is write in IDE